# findByIdAndRemove() deprication message

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**The following code produces the console message:**

**Message:**
(node:5700) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-findandmodify-

**Code:**

```html
app.post("/delete", (req, res) =>{
  const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;

  Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, (err) =>{
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Success!");
    } else {
      console.log("err");
    }
  });
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

I understand it has to do with depreciation and the method used in the background but I am confused as to how to deal with it. It doesn't break the app but still, I'd like to understand why this happen**s.

I tried the mongoose docs but I am still confused. Any and all help is appreciated.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html

The part under findAndModify is what I found relevant in the docs

I would like to not get the message. Is there an option that should be passed?

Comment: "deprecated" means that it still works, for now, but it **will** be removed in a future version, so you need to start using the new solution before you upgrade to a version that no longer supports what you're doing. In this case, the error literally tells you what you should do: pass the `useFindAndModify` option as part of the call, set to `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get rid of deprecations:

```
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
```

and fix the code, no more `findAndModify` style methods - which is correct, since if You want to delete - so `deleteOne`, `deleteMany`.
I don't see the reason to do find and delete when You don't care about if it exists or not.

about deprecations read under [SUMMARY here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html)

```
app.post("/delete", async (req, res) =>{
  try {
    const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
    await Item.deleteOne({_id: checkedItemId});
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  finally {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});
```